# Does the app need to be run by the user to get push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios

For example if a user installs my application and runs it, in which I will register for push notifications.

Then they turn of their phone and on again but this time never run my app.

Can I still push notifications to their device?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, so long as it's been run once and registered, you can send push notifications. Turning the device off and on again doesn't change anything.